# Angular project break into modules

Tags: angular, module, ng-modules

I'm building a web application in angular. In my application there are two major roles who can use the system. 
    **1. Teacher**
    **2. Student**

Both have different functions and different user interfaces.

Should i break my angular application into two modules like `teacherModule` and `studentModule` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not necessary to have two modules - you can have single module and access functions and load properties by getting the role - Because if you have multiple modules you need to spend some time and you need to use duplicate codes for common codes

While routing you can get the role of the user and use the functions based on that 
try using `Resolver` check this - https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard

Thanks - Happy coding !!

Answer (score 1):

for best practice Yes you should to make your app more organized that what it called `feature modules` also divide you app to feature modules makes using `lazy load` easy to manage step forward to optimize your app speed too.